# Why do docker CLI commands default to controlling containers?

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker, and one of the things I'm interested in WRT to it is what are the majority use-cases. For example, These commands seem to do the same thing:

```
docker container rm
```

and

```
docker rm
```

i.e. the CLI provides a shorthand means of controlling containers rather than images (the command `docker image ls` is also valid).

Why does docker choose to provide a short-hand means of working with containers rather than with images?

Comment: Take a look at the *CLI restructured* part of [Introducing Docker 1.13](https://blog.docker.com/2017/01/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience I work more with containers than with images. You create the image once but may create a container from this image multiple times.

I think this is similar to classes and objects. A image is just a blueprint for a container, same as a class is a blueprint for an object. You create multiple objects from a class but you write the class just once so in the end you will also execute more commands for containers than for images.

I think this is the reason why the commands are focused on the containers.

Comment: Thank you - speaking of images, I see that if I use `docker-compose` that no image is created (only the container)?

Comment: A docker-compose will always create an image (or does pull one) which then creates a container. No images means no container.

Comment: The command `docker image ls` doesn't seem to show me any images that might correspond to containers created by `docker-compose`. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I would have expected that the images are shown there. If you check your containers with `docker ps -a` it should show which image was used for the creation. Sometimes images are created as <none> which makes it difficult to find them.

Comment: ahhh. my image is just `node:8` - the containers are just using the standard image, and the projects that they are being built from (2 hello-world Node.js apps) don't have Dockerfiles. Therefore no image created